# jQuery get curent select's text

Tags: jquery, select

How can I get the current `<select>` text? I mean if I have selected the `<option name="me">ME</option>` how can I get its text?

Because the way I'm trying, returns all the texts inside the `<select>`

```
$('#action').change(function() {

    console.log($(this).text()); //this returns all the texts inside select
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
$('#action').change(function() {

    $(this).find(':selected').text(); 
});
```

Comment: Thx, this did it. But don't forget the `);` after the `}`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#" + $(this).attr("id") + " option:selected").text();
```

would work as well! But please use danish's solution!

Comment: This is weird, for some reason it grabs the text from all of my `selects` that have a selected option. lol! Tnx, anyway

Comment: fixed it! But I suggest using the find method().

Comment: oh, yea! I´ll use the find method for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text of a select by using

`$("#action option:selected").text();`

Comment: I'll try it, but the one that down voted should explain why. Tnx